# Uniform the distribution of characters in words dataset

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, dataset, algorithms, uniform-distribution

I have dataset of text images, each image contain 1 to 3 words. I need to predicate the sequence of characters in these images, however the distribution is very skewed. I found an algorithm in a paper, that try solve this same issue, but when I implement it the distribution of the set does not change. Essentially, this algorithm give weights to the images based on their characters, and say you want to add 100000 augmented images, you multiply each weight of image by this number and get how many of this image you need to add to get a better distribution of characters.

Distribution before and after:
[image]

```
## lexicon size, number of modeling units
l = len(set_abc_paths) # number of images
n = len(characters_as_unit_counter) # number of characters
total_chars = len(characters_as_unit)
## count of each modeling unit (character)
# characters_as_unit_counter[c] is the number of occurrences of a character in the images
dict_character_inv_prob = {c:(1 / (characters_as_unit_counter[c] / total_chars))  for c in list(characters_as_unit_counter.keys())}
dict_word_weight = {}
dict_word_weight_normlaized = {}
# dict_word_weight = {word: x for prob in dict_character_inv_prob for path in set_abc_paths}
weight_sum = 0.0
for path in set_abc_paths:
    label = os.path.basename(path)
# labels[label]['CharsAsUnit'] is list of characters in the image i.e ['aa', 'la', 'ma']
    dict_word_weight[label] = np.sum([dict_character_inv_prob[model] for model in labels[label]['CharsAsUnit']]) / len(labels[label]['CharsAsUnit']) 
    weight_sum += dict_word_weight[label]


for label in dict_word_weight:
    dict_word_weight_normlaized[label] = dict_word_weight[label] / weight_sum
```

I do not know if the problem in my implementation, or the algorithm is not correct. So, what I would like either for an alternative to achieve a close to uniform distribution, or a correction to this algorithm.

This is the pseudo code for the algorithm
[image]

Paper link can be found [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9091836)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of database is that but I think there are better algorithms than this one. try another methods for data balancing such as:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8353718

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8398919

I think those are much better than the one you put.